# Using native code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to use a C library in my Android application. The library depends on the gmp library. I have found a prebuilt version for it and I am trying to use it to build my library according to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) tutorial. However when I run my app I get this error
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libgmp.so" not found".
My CMakeLists file is this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        gmp
        SHARED
        IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(gmp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION gmp-master/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgmp.so)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")


add_library(
         ecc-lib
         SHARED
         src/main/cpp/lib)

target_include_directories( ecc-lib PRIVATE
                        src/main/cpp/include/
                        gmp-master/${ANDROID_ABI}/)

set_target_properties(ecc-lib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   ecc-lib
                   gmp
                  )
```

My MainActivity.java file contains this code:

```
package com.example.user.gmpapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Used to load the 'ecc-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ecc-lib");
}


// public native String ecdh();
}
```

Comment: I suppose that you verified the libgmp.so path, besides you can see where is located with message() function in cmake. You can post the code that of your MainActivity where you load the  ecc-lib library?

Comment: For the prebuilt gmplib I have also tried to create a jnilibs folder in the main directory however it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not CMake issue. It seems that your library is properly linked, it is more like library loading issue.

Your 3rdparty library (*libgmp.so*) is a shared library so it requires to load in execution time.

I think your problem may be fixed adding the library in main activity:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("gmp");
    System.loadLibrary("ecc-lib");
}
```

Notes:

- Add first the 3rdparty library because of the dependencies..
- If you can get the precompiled static .a library and link with your
  library you will not need to add the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I do that I get another error: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader" when I try to load the library.

Answer (score 0):

Check also this out: https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line

Here you can create Android application only with the command line all manually. It is very fast and it is almost like coding a regular .cpp software. In my view this is a gem.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. I tried to do the manual build of my library, however I am having trouble with make build. I changed the paths in the Cmake script and I made a similar folder structure as the native-activity example.

Comment: open an issue at the repository and also mention what the error is. I will have a look at it.